# Microsoft Graph snippets sample for ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Authentication error

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

As far as I know I have followed the instructions for setting up the Microsoft Graph sample https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample, including joining the Microsoft 365 Developer Program. However when I run the sample and attempt to log in with my new Developer Program user I get the following error message:

> Authentication error "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')"

The error us being caught in this routine:

```
options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
    var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Exception.Message);
    context.Response
        .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Authentication+error&debug={error}");
    context.HandleResponse();

    return Task.FromResult(0);
};
```

If I log in with my personal Microsoft account then everything works fine, so I'm guessing this has something to do with my Developer Program account. The error message isn't very helpful and there not stack trace to speak of. I've tried using Fiddler to see if there's any more information but with no luck either. Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) code says that NOTE: If you logged in with a personal account, snippets that aren't supported for Microsoft accounts are removed from the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and reproduced the issue. You are getting this error because, as you have created application in one tenant and accessing the application with the Developer Program account(another tenant).

The Solution would be provide  Provision for the application (service principal creation) Consent the application with the developer Program account(needs to be admin) if you want to use the application in developer tenant and Please below call

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44307%2F&prompt=admin_consent
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the error messages in the output from the Kestrel web server I discovered that the line causing the problem was this one:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(GraphClaimTypes.TimeZone, user.MailboxSettings.TimeZone));
```

and it was because the value of user.MailboxSettings.TimeZone was null. Once I set up a TimeZone in my developer account then everything works fine.